# Number Line Jumps HackerRank Algorithms Question

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am looking at the HackerRank problem [Number Line Jumps](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kangaroo/problem):

> You are choreographing a circus show with various animals. For one act, you are given two kangaroos on a number line ready to jump in the positive direction (i.e, toward positive infinity).
>
> - The first kangaroo starts at location 1 and moves at a rate of 1 meters per jump.
> - The second kangaroo starts at location 2 and moves at a rate of 2 meters per jump.
>
> You have to figure out a way to get both kangaroos at the same location at the same time as part of the show. If it is possible, return YES, otherwise return NO.
>
> #### Example
>
> 1 = 2
> 1 = 1
> 2 = 1
> 2 = 2
>
> After one jump, they are both at  = 3, (1 + 1 = 2 + 1, 2 + 2 = 1 + 2), so the answer is YES.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 0 ≤ 1 < 2 ≤ 10000
> 1 ≤ 1 ≤ 10000
> 1 ≤ 2 ≤ 10000

The algorithm I wrote doesn't pass all the tests case on HackerRank, I can't see where I'm doing wrong?

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    let   firstKangaroo = x1 + v1;
    let   secondKangaroo= x2 + v2;
    let   trueFalse = false; 
    let   maxLimit =  10000;
    let i = 0;
    for(;i <= maxLimit;i++) {
        if(firstKangaroo==secondKangaroo){
            trueFalse = true;
            break;
        }
    }
     return trueFalse ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

I threw it into the v1 variable with x1. I did the same for x2 and v2. I made the loop continue until 10000. If x1 + v1 = x2 + v2 then it should return true, not false. My code is running without errors, but it can't pass all the tests cases on HackerRank. I can't find where I went wrong.

Comment: Please don't put all your code on one line. Also I think you mean `==` instead of `=` for comparisons.

Comment: Why do you think it helps to *repepatedly* check whether `firstKangaroo==secondKangaroo`?

Comment: Where/what are "all the tests"?

Comment: Where are the tests and what is the algorithm ?! What is the point of the loop ?!

Comment: unclear how `if(firstKangaroo==secondKangaroo){` is ever going to change. The variables never change.

Comment: Would you expect this code to solve the problem?  `function kangaroo (x1, v1, x2, v2) {return x1 + v1 == x2 + v2 ? 'YES' : 'NO'}`?  Because in essence, that's all your function is doing, albeit in a very roundabout manner.

Comment: As kangaroos can jump as far as 9m, you may need quite a large circus tent, depending, of course, on the values of the four parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Several issues:

- In your loop nothing is happening with `firstKangaroo` nor `secondKangaroo` (they don't jump), so if in the first iteration they are not equal, they will still be unequal in the second, third, ... and all other iterations of the loop. So the loop serves no purpose.
- 10000 tries might not be enough to spot the jump where both kangaroos meet.

Moreover, this idea is not efficient. Look at the mathematics of this problem:

If the kangaroos meet, then there must be a number of jumps `k` such that:

```
x1 + k*v1 == x2 + k*v2
```

So then

```
(x1 - x2) == k*(v2 - v1)
```

...and that `k` must be an unsigned integer, i.e. we should check that `(x1 - x2)` is a multiple of `(v2 - v1)`. Also their signs should be the same, and then the remainder after division should be 0 -- we can use the `%` operator for that.

So:

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    return Math.sign(x1 - x2) === Math.sign(v2 - v1) && 
          ( v1 === v2 || (x1 - x2) % Math.abs(v2 - v1) === 0) ? "YES" : "NO";
}

// Test run:
console.log(kangaroo(0, 2, 5, 3));
```

As in the code challenge it is given that `x1 < x2` we can simplify a bit:

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    return v2 < v1 && (x2 - x1) % (v1 - v2) === 0 ? "YES" : "NO";
}

// Test run:
console.log(kangaroo(0, 2, 5, 3));
```

Comment: This fails in the case `x1 == x2` and `v1 == v2`.  Obviously it's a simple enough fix.

Comment: The code challenge says that `x1 < x2`. This is what I mentioned when I introduced the simplified solution. The first version does not assume this, and also works for `x1 >= x2` (assuming that 0 jumps is an acceptable solution).

Comment: Ah, yes.  I saw all the `≤` and thought that was all of them.  I didn't really look through your derivation, only looked at the final answer.  Sorry about that!

Comment: kangaroo(0 ,10 ,8, 8) = Yes (they will meet at 40)
why kangaroo(0 ,20 ,8, 8) = No (they will also meet at 40, right?)

Comment: @keepscoding, it may not be very clear from the challenge, but the kangaroos make their jumps at the same time, so they should meet after the same number of jumps. This is inferred by *"at the same time"*, and the example that says *"After one jump, they are..."*.

Comment: @trincot make sense "jumps at the same time", thanks

Answer (score 1):

from simple rule of motion, the question says the kangaroos jump at a rate of v. This means m/s. Therefore, if they both start at whatever point and is to meet at a particular point, at the same time,

```
 if x1 > x2 and v2 > v1:
    if (x1-x2)%(v2-v1)==0:
        return "YES"
 elif x2>x1 and v1>v2:
    if (x2-x1)%(v1-v2) == 0:
        return "YES"
 return "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, different from trincot's mathematical analysis is to test until the faster-moving kangaroo is ahead of the slower one, stopping if they meet.  If they haven't by then, they never will.  We can do this with a simple enough recursion:

```js
const kangaroo = (x1, v1, x2, v2) => 
  v1 < v2
    ? kangaroo (x2, v2, x1, v1)
  : x1 == x2
    ? 'YES'
  : v1 == v2
    ? 'NO'
  :  x1 > x2
    ? 'NO'
  : kangaroo (x1 + v1, v1, x2 + v2, v2)


console .log (kangaroo (0, 3, 4, 2))
console .log (kangaroo (0, 2, 5, 3))
```

If the faster one is second, we swap them.  If they're already in the same spot, we're done.  If not, and they have the same-size jump, they can never meet.  If the faster one is ahead of the slower one, then they won't ever meet.  Otherwise, we make a jump (by incrementing `x1` by `v1` and `x2` by `v2`) and test again.

Answer (score 0):

kangaroo hackerrank solution javascript. Easy to understand.

```
let result="NO";
    for(let i=0; i<10000; i++){
        if((x1+(v1*i))==(x2+(v2*i))){
            result="YES";
        }
    }
    return(result);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    let   firstKangaroo = x1 + v1;
    let   secondKangaroo= x2 + v2;
    let   trueFalse = false; 
    let   maxLimit =  10000;
    let i = 0;
    for(;i <= maxLimit;i++) {
        if(firstKangaroo==secondKangaroo){
            trueFalse = true;
            break;
        }else
         {  firstKangaroo += v1; 
            secondKangaroo += v2;
        }
    }
     return trueFalse ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
// Write your code here
var num = (x1-x2)%(v2-v1);
var num2 =(x1-x2)/(v2-v1);
var result = '';
//X1 = x1 + v1 * num;
//X2 = x2 + v2 * num;
if(isNaN(num) || num != 0 || num2<0){
    result='NO';
} else if (num===0){
    result='YES';
} 
return String(result);

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
  if(v1 < v2) {
    return "NO";
  }
  if((x2 - x1) % (v2 -v1) == 0) {
    return "YES";
  } else {
    return "NO";
  }
 
}
```